# Uncheck all RadioButton in a RadioButtonGroup

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

What I wanted to achieve is this: Right after the activity starts, I want that no RadioButton is selected/checked.

My problem is this: When the activity starts, the first RadioButton is always selected/checked.

I tried `radioButton1.setChecked(false)` right after initialization of the radiobutton(inside onCreate), but when the activity starts, I can't manually check/select the first radiobutton. Till I select the 2nd or 3rd radio button, I can now select/check the first radio button.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
radioGroup.clearCheck();
```

Comment: As far I know, there is no class named "RadioButtonGroup". Instead of this, the appropriate class name is "RadioGroup". Beyond this tiny fact, the above codes are precisely workable!.

Comment: what if we want to do that in OnCheckedChangeListener ??
for future question why do you do that i have different type views in radio grp in addition to radio btn !

Comment: Is there a way to do that without the wacky unchecking animation?

Answer (score 4):

use clearCheck() for clearing all checked radiobutton when acticity is started or resumed

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RG);
rg.clearCheck();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {  
RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RG);
rg.clearCheck();  
super.onResume();  
    }
```

Comment: after setting this radio button background drawable selector not working

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
RadioButton spec1=findViewById(yourRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if (spec1.isChecked())
        {
            spec1.setChecked(false);
        }
```