# Using <RadioGroup> to set all <RadioButton> checked false

Tags: android

I would like to know if it possible to use the RadioGroup to set all RadioButtons to a specified value. In my case I have this:

```
public void displayFalse(View view) {

    if(view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers)

        for (int i = 0; i < rgPrimer.getChildCount(); i++) {
            rgSegon.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            //something like: .setChecked(false);

    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons){

        for (int i = 0; i < rgSegon.getChildCount(); i++) {
            rgSegon.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons) {

        for (int i = 0; i < rgPostre.getChildCount(); i++) {
            rgPostre.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {

    }

}
```

So I have different `<LinearLayout>` where each one is visible using a button. So if the button has been selected, the layout will appear and so will all the radioGroup inside. So here I check for the button selected and then I get inside the radioGroup that is in that layout and just set them false.

I have tried as well:

```
public void displayFalse(View view) {

    if(view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers){

        rbPrimer1.setChecked(false);
        rbPrimer2.setChecked(false);
        rbPrimer3.setChecked(false);
        rbPrimer4.setChecked(false);

    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons){

        rbSegon1.setChecked(false);
        rbSegon2.setChecked(false);
        rbSegon3.setChecked(false);
        rbSegon4.setChecked(false);

    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons) {

        rbPostre1.setChecked(false);
        rbPostre2.setChecked(false);
        rbPostre3.setChecked(false);
        rbPostre4.setChecked(false);

    } else {

    }
```

But it doesn't either work. How can I fix the issue and is there a improved version?

Comment: try using radiogroup.clearcheck(); [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10497945/6422177)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup) has a method:

```
clearCheck()
```

It does exactly what you want:

```
public void displayFalse(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers)
        rgSegon.clearCheck(); //is this the right RadioGroup?
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons) {
        rgSegon.clearCheck();
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons) { //is this the right ID?
        rgPostre.clearCheck();
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, great to know. :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);radioGroup.clearCheck();
```